# Cannot read site collection details with some accounts

Tags: 2010, permissions, security, central-administration

In my SharePoint environment, I have a few seperate web applications with some different admin users. Now a new user I created is added as local admin (needed for Powershell remoting) and farm admin. But for some reason, it cannot read the details of some site collcetions and I don't know why.

For instance: when I open up central admin and log in as this new user, I can browse to the section where you config site collection administrators. I can select a site collection and some info (URL, title, description, etc) is shown as soon as I select one. But some site collections I select and nothing shows; the info section remains empty. When I now press OK, the page reloads (as it normally does), but nothing is selected. Apparantly I don't have rights. But weirdly enough I do have rights to other sites in the same web application.

You'd think that this has something to do with the configured site collection administrators, but it doesn't. Because when I take another farm admin, which also isn't a site collection admin, I do see details and I'm able to change things. So there's some other level of permissions I'm missing apparantly, but I don't know what that could be. Who knows?

Comment: Do you see errors in the event log? Sometimes it will tell you when you are trying to access a database and don't have permission.

Comment: The log lists a permission denied error, but doesn't state to what permission was denied or why. So it's not that helpful unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try running Add-SPShellAdmin for the other farm admin account just to be sure he gets all the rights properly. Refer to this [blog](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/itpro/Pages/Creating-Additional-SharePoint-2010-Farm-Administrators.aspx) for usage

Comment: Doesn't make any difference